# How to add 'timestamp' and 'owner' to 'bibtex-clean-entry'?

Tags: bibtex

I am a recent and happy user of BibTeX mode (`bibtex.el`), but there is one thing I can't get to work as I wish. When I create a template, I can enforce insertion of timestamp and owner with:

```
(defun current-date ()
    (format-time-string "%Y.%m.%d"))    
(setq
    bibtex-user-optional-fields '(
                                 ("timestamp" "Time the entry was created" current-date)
                                 ("owner" "Owner of the entry" user-login-name)
)
```

Is this possible to have the same behavior with `bibtex-clean-entry` (`C-c C-c`), which would automatically add the timestamp and the owner if they are not already set?

---

The rationale behind that is that I'm using `biblio.el` for automatic download of references (e.g. via DOI), and I set it to run `bibtex-clean-entry` right away with:

```
(setq biblio-cleanup-bibtex-function #'bibtex-clean-entry)
```

Being able to have the behavior described above for this function would actually save me a lot of time… and make sure I don't forget to add both fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something I've wanted too. I've implemented it for the timestamp as follows:

First, we need a function to add the timestamp if it doesn't exist already. In my system I call the time stamp `date_added`, just swap that out for `timestamp` for your system:

```el
(defun bibty-add-date ()
  "Adds a date_added field to a bibtex entry.
Checks to make sure it doesn't exist first."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (bibtex-beginning-of-entry)
    (if (assoc "date_added" (bibtex-parse-entry))
        (message "date_added already exists!")
      (bibtex-end-of-entry) ;; if you want date_added always at the end
      (bibtex-make-field '("date_added" nil current-date) t nil))))
      ;; NB: current-date is @MathieuBasille's custom function from the question
```

I made this function interactive, as I often want to manually add the date_added, so it's convenient to bind this to `C-c d`.

To get this function to run whenever you run `bibtex-clean-entry`, add it to the hook:

```
(add-hook 'bibtex-clean-entry-hook 'bibty-add-date)
```

You can use the same approach for your `owner` field.

I maintain the [bibtex-utils](https://github.com/plantarum/bibtex-utils) package; I should, eventually, put together a more generic approach to accomplish this for arbitrary fields and add it to the package. In the meantime hopefully this works well enough.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I had to remove the `(bibtex-end-of-entry)` which was actually moving out of the entry (right after to be precise). I also adapted to `bibtex-add-date-owner` with a check and insertion of `user-login-name`.

Comment: Also, I have been in contact with Roland Winkler, maintainer of `bibtex.el`. I just forwarded him your answer, maybe he'll be able to implement it directly in `bibtex.el`.

Comment: I found some problems with `bibtex-end-of-entry` as well. For me it works more consistently if I follow that with a `(forward-char -1)`, which ensures that `date_added` is the last field in the entry.